# Build multiple versions of static library from one Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

I have several projects A through F that each depend on static library L. Each is a project in my visual studio solution.

Unfortunately, project F needs a slightly different flavor of the static library to be built (currently implemented by defining a preprocessor directive in the build options to select a different code segment using if/endif directives, since the special case code adds additional dependencies that projects A-E don't care about).

I currently solve this problem by making a second library project "L_withflag" that includes all of the same source files, and that works just fine. I'm wondering if there is an easier way that doesn't require maintaining two separate projects with the same underlying codebase.

Is there a way that I can get static library project L to build two outputs, one with the flag set and one without (e.g. L.lib and L_withflag.lib) and allow each project to specify which library it wants as input?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio lets you have multiple build configurations for a solution.  By default for C++ you'll get Debug and Release configurations, but you can add additional configurations by going to

```
Build > Configuration Manager > Active Solution Configuration (pull down list) > New
```

When choosing New you can copy settings from an existing configuration (Debug, Release). So you can create configurations "Release - Options A", "Release - Options B" then edit the project settings for each to set different preprocessor directives.

In the project settings you can also set different DLL names and/or output folders.

Comment: Yup, I can add those additional configurations, but I need both configurations to build in order to satisfy the dependencies for all of my projects. This gets me to being able to build the two dependency trees separately I guess and I could do a batch build. Is that what you're suggesting?